# Efficiently creating NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot with a lot of sections and items

Tags: uicollectionview, ios13

Given a need to create a static collection view that contains hundreds of thousands of items across hundreds of sections, how could one efficiently create the `NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot`?

In Apple's sample code, [`UsingCollectionViewCompositionalLayoutsAndDiffableDataSources`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/collection_views/using_collection_view_compositional_layouts_and_diffable_data_sources) they follow this pattern:

```
let itemsPerSection = 1000
let sections = Array(0..<250)
var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Int, Int>()
var itemOffset = 0
sections.forEach {
    snapshot.appendSections([$0])
    snapshot.appendItems(Array(itemOffset..<itemOffset + itemsPerSection))
    itemOffset += itemsPerSection
}
```

Each section and item have to be unique identifiers. The inefficiency comes in creating an array of 1000 `Int`s, and doing that 250x. In this example, it takes about 12 seconds to generate on my device.

Is there a different way to generate this structure efficiently, any way to avoid generating it up-front, or is this not going to be possible with the architecture of snapshots?

Comment: Using the traditional `UICollectionViewDataSource` is quite a lot more efficient, for anyone who is in a similar situation. Still curious if the diffable data source be more efficient because it's such a nice API I'd like to use it.

Comment: Can't reproduce. I ran the code you provided (changing `let` to `var`) and it took negligible time. Maybe your mistake is applying the snapshot without remembering to turn off animation?

Comment: Confirmed, performance has been very greatly improved down to about 0.7 seconds instead of 12, at least as of the iOS 13.1 SDK.

Answer (score 5):

You can build your snapshot incrementally like you would with a traditional data source. First, create the snapshot with the initial items and, when you determine there is a need for more, rebuild it with the additional items.

If you don’t want to rebuild the snapshot from scratch every time you add more items, you can get the table’s existing snapshot from its diffable data source’s `snapshot()` function and then manually add the additional items using the snapshot’s functions such as `insertItems`, `insertSections`, etc.